# Configure Subversion on Win7/x64 to use a proxy server

Tags: svn, windows-7, proxy

How does one configure a subversion client (either TortoiseSVN or CollabNet command-line) on a Win7/x64 platform for use with a proxy server?

### What I have tried so far

### (1) CollabNet command-line

The following command line, invoking CollabNet's command-line svn client works perfectly well on an XP system, but with exactly the same configuration (after localising paths) does **NOT** work.

```
"<Path-to-svn>\svn.exe"
  --config-dir "<Path-to-subversion-config-dir>"
  --config-option servers:global:http-proxy-host=<Proxy>
  --config-option servers:global:http-proxy-port:8080
  checkout http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tools/gcmole C:\TEMP\t1\v8
```

In the above command-line listing, new-lines have been added for readability, and place-markers are indicated with angle brackets, like `<Path-to-svn>`.

On Win7/x64, the above command returns error message:

```
svn: E170001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tools/gcmol'
svn: E170001: OPTIONS of 'http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tools/gcmole':authorization failed: Could not authenticate to proxy server: could not parse challenge (http://v8.googlecode.com)
```

### (2) TortoiseSVN

On an XP machine, SVN works perfectly well. The network options of the TortoiseSVN settings are configured correctly. On a Win7/x64 machine with exactly the same configuration, any svn operation returns error message ...

```
Unable to connect to repository at URL 'http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk'
Error running context: An error occurred during authentication
```

Similar errors occur with TortoiseSVN command-line on Win7/x64, but the same command-line on XP with the same configuration works well.

### (3) Firewall issues

All potential firewall issues have been tested. There are no firewall issues.

What am I missing? How do I get subversion to work on Win7/x64 when I am behind a proxy server?

Comment: This is a perfectly good, well asked question. Whenever some nut-job down-votes a good well asked question, it undermines the whole voting system.

Answer (score 0):

```
"<Path-to-svn>\svn.exe"
  --config-dir "<Path-to-subversion-config-dir>"
  --config-option servers:global:http-proxy-host=<Proxy>
  --config-option servers:global:http-proxy-port:8080
  checkout http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tools/gcmole C:\TEMP\t1\v8
```

The second line is meaningless. Use either `--config-option` or `--config-dir`. The default client configuration is located in `%APPDATA%\Subversion`.

To solve proxy authentication errors check the configuration you have in your  or %APPDATA%\Subversion on the Windows XP machine. I guess that your proxy server requires authentication and on Windows XP machine Runtime Config already has username and password specified but other machines don't have it therefore authentication fails. Look for `http-proxy-username` and `http-proxy-password` arguments in `Servers` file and in Windows Registry branch `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Tigris.org\Subversion\Servers\`.

Read [**SVNBook | Runtime Configuration Area**](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/confarea/).

Comment: This is not the answer. The servers file on both platforms are identical, except for path localisation. Adding or removing http-proxy-username/password makes no difference to the outcome (tested). On an XP machine (and I suspect on Win7 too), not specifying the credentials is fine when the proxy credentials are the same as the o/s log-on credentials)

Comment: So you mean that you've checked %APPDATA%\Subversion\servers, checked Windows Registry and <Path-to-subversion-config-dir>? And all is the same on both machines?